# Calculating odds

Tags: probability

So my question is:

Lets assume we have a raffle with 5000 tickets in it, there will be one winner for the raffle. If someone buys one ticket then the odds of them winning the prize is 1/5000, if they buy 2 tickets then the odds are 2/5000 but would that also mean 1/2500? and if they bought 4 tickets 1/1250? am I making a silly mistake here, I basically just need to know how to calculate the odds depending on the amount of tickets bought...
very grateful to anyone that can clarify this please?

Comment: All of those examples are correct.  If you buy $n$ tickets you have a $\frac n{5000}$ probability of winning.  If you buy all $5000$ tickets, you will win with probability $1$, for instance.

Comment: Note... this works given that all of these tickets being purchased are from *the same raffle*.  If I were to buy a ticket from raffle A which has $5000$ tickets, and then I were to also buy a ticket from an unrelated raffle B which also has $5000$ tickets, then the probability of me winning at least one of the raffles is not $\frac{2}{5000}$ but is instead $\frac{1}{5000}+\frac{1}{5000}\color{red}{-\frac{1}{5000^2}}$.  In the same way, if I roll two dice, the probability of getting at least one six is not $\frac{2}{6}$ but is instead $\frac{11}{36}$

Answer (score 1):

If you buy $n$ tickets for a single raffle, then it works the way you said, so you have $\frac{n}{5000}$ chance to win, but if these tickets are for different raffles, you would have to make more calculations.

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples are correct.  More broadly, if you buy $n$ tickets, for $0≤n≤5000$ the probability of winning is $$\frac n{5000}$$

If, in particular, you buy $5000$ tickets your probability of winning is $1$.